# Orbeon localisation

Tags: orbeon

I translated the necessary files for Dutch but apparently the runner still shows the error section in English.

[image: error message]

 I looked at both the runner and fb resource.xml but couldn't find the string 'Your form contains the following errors'.

I also have this entries in the properties-local.xml

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.available-languages.orbeon.builder"  value="nl en"/> 
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.default-language.orbeon.builder"     value="nl"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.default-language.orbeon.*"           value="nl"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.default-language.*.*"                value="nl"/>
```

Comment: Sorry we didn't see your question earlier. I answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends which version you are using:

- up to Orbeon Forms 4.2, [resources.xml](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.2-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml#L25) does contain that message
- starting Orbeon Forms 4.3, [resources.xml](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.3-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml#L25) contains a more complex formatted string